# Implement a custom layer after a series of MPSCNNConvolution

Tags: ios, neural-network, convolution, conv-neural-network, metal

I have a custom neural net here, made mostly of the usual building block (conv, relu, max pool, etc).

But the last layer needs a sigmoid on some feature channels, and softmax on others (trying to predict classes, and a confidence index).

Anyway, I'm trying to build a Metal operation on the MPSImage.texture at the end of my convolutions.

Here is where it gets hairy. I think each `conv_img.texture` array entry contains 4 layers of my neural net (one per each channel of `rgba`)

If I have my custom metal thread code, I'll be getting one value that corresponds to 4 layers per grid entry.

Here is my sigmoid example, which is supposed to take grid values at the desired layer, and store the output value in some other layer.

I don't think it would work for the reason mentioned above.

I'd love some help, or some example of custom layers implemented after some Apple provided `MPSConvolution`.

```
kernel void sigmoid(texture2d_array<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
                    texture2d_array<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
                    uint3 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {

    if (gid.x >= outTexture.get_width()
        || gid.y >= outTexture.get_height()
        || gid.z >= outTexture.get_array_size()) {
        return;
    }

    const uint classes = 80;
    const uint coords = 4;
    const uint size_pred = (classes + coords + 1);

    uint layer = size_pred * gid.z + 4;
    float4 x = inTexture.read(uint2(gid.x, gid.y), layer);
    float4 y = float4(1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x)));
    outTexture.write(y, uint2(gid.x, gid.y), gid.z);
}
```

EDIT:  this is how I've been trying to debug it 
In the final buffer with all the values, I should see something
that looks like my thread grid originally.
But it doesn't seem to work.

```
kernel void sigmoid(texture2d_array<float, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
                    texture2d_array<float, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
                    uint3 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (gid.x >= outTexture.get_width()
        || gid.y >= outTexture.get_height()
        || gid.z >= outTexture.get_array_size()) {
        return;
    }

    const uint classes = 80;
    const uint coords = 4;
    const uint texture_channels = 4;
    const uint size_pred = (classes + coords + 1) / texture_channels;

    const uint layer = size_pred * gid.z + 4;
    const uint offset = layer % texture_channels;
    const float4 channels = inTexture.read(uint2(gid.x, gid.y), layer);
    // const float r = x[0]
    // const float g = x[1]
    // const float b = x[2]
    // const float a = x[3]
    const float channel_of_interest = channels[offset];

    // in the output buffer should see a bunch of numbers that look 
    // like the thread grid
    const float y = gid.x * 10000 + gid.y * 10 + gid.z;
    // float y = float(1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-channel_of_interest)));
    const uint new_offset = gid.z % texture_channels;
    float4 new_channels = 0;
    new_channels[new_offset] = y;
    outTexture.write(y, uint2(gid.x, gid.y), gid.z);
}
```

Comment: Your understanding of the channel layout is correct. Presumably, you can compute which activation function to use based on the  current thread's position in the grid. If so, you can just between sigmoid and softmax inside the kernel function. Of course, if you know in advance that the channels that need each function are divided into two large, contiguous ranges, you could dispatch multiple grids, using one or the other function as appropriate (handling the boundary with a third kernel). In the worst case, you could create an auxiliiary 3D texture that indicates which function to apply.

Comment: So my question is: is there any "structure" to which channels need each activation function applied? How "frequently" does the function change relative to the grid indices?

Comment: Yes, I have 4 layers of coordinates, 1 layer of 'confidence value', and then 80 layers one per class. the whole thing repeated 5 times, for a total of 425 layers.

I could extract the 5 layers of confidence and apply the sigmoid function at once on each cell. The softmax function would have to be on each bundle of 80 I think.

So in my scenario above I should apply the sigmoid function on only one element of the float4, is that how that works ?

Comment: I know how to extract all the values into a big float buffer, but I would rather do the final activation still in that same "commandBuffer context".
Could you guide me into applying the correct kernel, or how I would extract the layers into a different arrangement in a different texture.